# error after installing and while compiling react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

The react app has been installed but after trying to compile, it shows 1 error on the browser as well as on the console that.

ERROR:

> [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json »
> eslint-config-react-app »
> C:\Users\Dell\desktop\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js"
> and "BaseConfig »
> C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

I tried to delete one of the files that have been installed twice however when tried to delete baseconfig, it wouldn't run at all but after deleting package.Json it would run but still show the same error that there are two similar files even though I tried deleting it.
I deleted the file after arriving through the path given above, but I don't think that is the correct path, can anyone tell me the path that I should write to arrive at these folders that have similar files or what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove node_module and Lock file then again install dependencies. I am pretty sure this will fix your error

Comment: yeah thanks, it seems i just needed to delete it from my package.json by going inside my VScode